# Raspberry Pi 4 as a Wifi Hotspot with RaspAp + VPN + Pi Hole

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, vpn, access-point, hotspot

I'm sure it has been discussed before, but I can't find the right answer after spending hours with googleing. 
I'm new to this device, I just got my new RP 4 and here's what I'd like to use it for:
- to attach to my home router and set up RP as a Wifi access point. 
- use VPN service on the device, so all connected devices through Wifi would be protected by VPN
- Have Pi-Hole as a ad blocker

The Pi is "headless", connected with a Ethernet cable.

I have tried to install RaspAP, after rebooting I started customizing the hotspot settings, so when I change it to 5 GHz network, the wifi gets ruined and I get "no wireless interface found" error message.

Anyways, I installed Pi-Hole, after that I had no internet on the device at all. At that point I erased the SD card and started all over again.

I was following these tutorials:
https://howtoraspberrypi.com/create-a-wi-fi-hotspot-in-less-than-10-minutes-with-pi-raspberry/ - 10 minutes became days of work lol

I don't want to give it up....I need help :)

Comment: This is a very broad question! The only "help" that I can offer: install and play with each of the application separately to understand what all the pieces are that make it work. Only then try and make them work together on one system.

Comment: Did you install "OpenWrt"?